# shared_ptr to abstract base class (member variable) is a an undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

The following struct should hold a shared_ptr to an abstract base class (*Shape*). However, when I try to write this, I get `error C2065: 'Shape' : undeclared identifier`.

So I know that I can't create instances of Shape, only instances of the derived Spheres, Boxes, etc. But why can't I use a shared_ptr to an abstract base class?

```
#include <memory>  // std::shared_ptr

#include "shape.hpp"

struct Hit {
    // …

    std::shared_ptr<Shape> m_shape;  // Shape that was hit
};
```

It should be noted that indeed the Shape class is using the Hit struct and vice versa.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is probably in `shape.hpp`.

Comment: I bet one leek that `shape.hpp` includes `hit.hpp`.

Comment: @Quentin This is correct. Both files indeed include each other.

Comment: Leave a leek on the windowsill tonight ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `#include "shape.hpp"` in the above with the *forward declaratio*n

`class Shape;` (you might need `struct Shape;` depending on how `Shape` is declared).

This is possible since class members of type `std::shared_ptr` can be declared with an *incomplete type*.

This helps you to untangle circular inclusions. Of course, the source file that defines the functions for `struct Hit` will need to `#include` `shape.hpp`.

Comment: In the case of having only a `hit.hpp` and no cpp file (There is only constructors and member declarations), am I leaving `#include "shape.hpp"` or am I introducing a cpp file?

Comment: For an easy life, introduce a `.cpp` file.

Comment: And sources will be more readable when you have hpp and cpp file pair ...